# Distributing SQL Server Express without an installer (e.g. loose DLLs)?

Tags: sql, sql-server-express

Is it possible to distribute SQL Server Express as just a loose collection of modules (DLLs)?

We have an internal C# tool that uses a SQL server to create a temporary database for consumption by an C++ tool using ODBC.  The dependency on SQL server makes the whole process unnecessarily fragile and slow due to network issues.  If we could instead host the temporary database locally it would make our process much more reliable and a fair bit faster.

The only thing is we distribute the internal tool as a collection of EXEs and DLLs: so I'd need SQL Express in DLL form not the conventional installer distribution.  Is that possible?

Comment: It is too bad you aren't using SQLite. That would have made things MUCH easier.

Comment: I think the installer supports network-type installs using command-line parameters and whatnot. Is that unsuitable?

Comment: I was just thinking SQLite could be the way to go, I going to look for  an decent SQLite ODBC implementation.

Comment: Not sure if ODBC drivers exist yet, but you may want to take a look at the new SQL CE 4.0

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server [Compact Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/compact.aspx) is more like what I want, as it supports xcopy style deployment.  Although it does not support ODBC so I may have to port the C++ code to OLEDB.

The alternative would be to use [SQLite via ODBC](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/) instead, that will need a separate OLEDB driver for SQLite (for the C# tool).